# How do I insert an image into my Java applet?

Tags: java

Basically I have to write a Java applet that produces a business card. The part I'm stuck on is figuring out how to display an image of myself in the applet.

The part I'm confused about in my directions is that it says:

> This assumes you have an image in the directory of your BlueJ project called 'businesscard.jpg'

How do I get my picture into the directory of my BlueJ project even?  How do I then get the code the right way so it appears in the applet?

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.*;


public class BusinessCard extends JApplet
{


    public void paint(Graphics page)
    {
        //Variables used in rectangle
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int width = 500;
        int height = 300;

        page.drawRect(x, y, width, height);  //draws the rectangle using variables

        //Displays name
        Font f = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 26);
        page.setFont(f);
        page.drawString ("anon", 300,100);

        //Displays company
        Font g = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18);
        page.setFont(g);
       page.drawString ("anon", 320, 120);

        //Displays email
        Font h = new Font("serif", Font.ITALIC, 15);
        page.setFont(h);
        page.drawString ("email", 320,140);

        //int for the logo
        final int MID = 350;
        final int TOP = 168;

        page.setColor (Color.orange);
        page.fillOval (MID, TOP, 60, 60); //bottom half of the trophy. the rounded part.
        page.drawArc (MID-8, TOP+15, 25, 25, 100, 160); //left arc
        page.drawArc (MID+43, TOP+15 , 25, 25, 280, 160); //right arc
        page.fillRect (MID+1, TOP+1, 59, 25); //make the top of the trophy flat basically
        page.fillRect (MID+22, TOP+60, 15, 25); //neck of the trophy
        page.drawLine (MID+48, TOP+84, MID+10, TOP+84); //base of the trophy

        page.setColor (Color.blue);
        Font i = new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20); 
        page.setFont(i);
        page.drawString ("#1", MID+20, TOP+30); //Creates the "#1" on the trophy.


        //The following is all code for inserting my image


          BufferedImage photo = null;

        try {
            URL u = new URL(getCodeBase(), "businesscard.jpg");
            photo = ImageIO.read(u);
        }   catch (IOException e) {
            page.drawString("Problem reading the file", 100, 100);
        }

        page.drawImage(photo, 10, 10, 150, 225, null);




    }


}
```

Comment: Can't you just copy it there?

Comment: We are not here to do your work for you. Had you had a read through the tutorials they will answer allot of your questions. Working with images: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html and I/O: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

Comment: I wasn't asking anyone to do my work for me. Java is very new and confusing to, as I stated, and even little things are difficult for me. Including locating guides that are specifically relevant to my problem. So I am very thankful and appreciate the links you have provided. I never asked anyone to finish my applet for me but rather I was seeking a nudge in the right direction because I am incredibly inexperienced. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class Photo extends Applet
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {        
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;
      int width = 500;
      int height = 300;                     
      BufferedImage photo = null;
      try 
      {
         URL u = new URL(getCodeBase(),"Bike.jpg");
         photo = ImageIO.read(u);
      }   
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
         g.drawString("Problem reading the file", 100, 100);
      }
         g.drawImage(photo,x, y, width, height,null);
   }
}
```